# Attributes of super object

Tags: python, python-2.7, super

```
class Mysuper(object):

    def aaa(self):
        print "In Superclass"


class Mysub(Mysuper):

    def aaa(self):
        ss = super(Mysub, self)
        print dir(ss) , type(ss)
        print ss.__dict__
        ss.aaa()
        print "In Subclass"

>>> ob = Mysub()
>>> ob.aaa()
['__class__', '__delattr__', '__doc__', '__format__', '__get__', '__getattribute__', '__hash__', '__init__', '__new__', '__reduce__',   '__reduce_ex__', '__repr__', '__self__', '__self_class__', '__setattr__',   '__sizeof__', '__str__', '__subclasshook__', '__thisclass__'] <type 'super'>
{}
In Superclass
In Subclass
>>>
```

Why isn't the attribute `aaa` listed for `super` object ?
Since the attribute is not listed how is `super` object `ss` able to call `aaa()` in the class `Mysuper`?

Comment: Why would you expect it to have a `aaa` attribute? You have already concluded, that `ss` is neither `Mysuper` class nor its instance, but instance of `<type 'super'>`. Why exactly `super` instance should have an `aaa` member?

Comment: @Rogalski Added another query, please see above.

Comment: it's basically some `__getattribute__` magic. [Use the source, Luke!](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Objects/typeobject.c#L7393). `super_getattro` is what you want.

Comment: @abc You should accept an answer if it helped you.

Answer (score 0):

Methods are contained in the class dict, not the instance dict.

See this:

```
class C:
    def method(self): pass

print(C().__dict__)  # prints {}
print(C.__dict__)  # prints a lot of stuff plus the method
```

The inheritance does not play a role here.

Using `super`:

> `super`: Return a proxy object that delegates method calls to a parent or sibling class

With `super(SomeType, some_instance)` you get a proxy to the **object**, not the **type**. So calling `dir` on that proxy object will get you the instance dict of the super object which does not contain any of your defined methods or attribute and getting the `__dict__` attribute only shows instance attributes of the object behind the proxy. The methods instead are again on the class dict of the object behind that proxy.

Answer (score -2):

When you pass self to super(Mysub,self) you are binding self as an instance of the superclass. If you omit self you won't see aaa as an attribute.